# ModuleNotFoundError: Python files seem to behave differentely inside and outside of Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Some months ago, I developed a project using PyCharm and it worked just fine. Now if I want to enter the venv `venv\Scripts\activate` and start the project from cmd `python src\main.py`, I receive `ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'src'` when main.py and other files try to import stuff from src.

When I move all my files from src to the project root folder, it straightens out. A lot has happened with this project and my Python environment, but that's frankly besides the point.

Why does *main.py* "see" the project from the root in PyCharm, but now in command line it doesn't? And how can I deal with it?

Comment: post the complete error

Comment: If you want to make it not work in PyCharm, too, you can right-click the src directory and 'unmark' it as a source root -- which is how PyCharm knows to add it to the PYTHONPATH variable, IIRC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the project tree

```
.
└── src
    ├── lib.py
    └── main.py
```

... with `main.py`

```py
import src.lib
```

When you run `main.py` in PyCharm it adds the project root to `PYTHONPATH` by default. Hence when Python tries to resolve `import src.lib`, it successfully finds package `src` in `sys.path` under the project root.

When you run `python src/main.py` - the project root is not added to `PYTHONPATH`, only `src/` itself (parent folder of the executed module). So Python cannot resolve `import src` as the `src` package is nowhere to be found under `sys.path` entries.

I hope it makes sense.

You can emulate PyCharm's behavior in the terminal with

```
PYTHONPATH=. python src/main.py
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! To other guys reading this, if you want to containerize your app with Docker, you should also add  ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app/src" (but with your own path) to Dockerfile.